# SoundCloud Explicit Intent sharing: setting "Client ID"

Tags: android, soundcloud

I'm currently using the SoundCloud Explicit Intent sharing mechanism, as described in:

```
https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing/wiki
```

I tried emulating what can be seen in the example code provided here:

```
https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing/blob/master/src/com/soundcloud/android/examples/intent/Record.java
```

Everything works fine **BUT** [this part](https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing/blob/master/src/com/soundcloud/android/examples/intent/Record.java#L167).

What happens is that the string

```
  "soundcloud:created-with-client-id=" + CLIENT_ID
```

bit just ends up in the track's tags, without CLIENT_ID finally being replaced by the actual Application name on the track's page (the application is already registered and I have a client_id).

Any ideas?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need the client id in tags so we don't lose the "real" client_id information - however it is not used to actually display the name of the app in the interface. This might change though.

See https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing/wiki/Explicit-intent-sharing#wiki-preserving_client_id

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jan, I see that ATM the only solution would be to use Token sharing.